# How to disable surrounding braces on Selected Text

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I've latest Visual Studio + Resharper. Some time ago VS started highlighting selected text with brackets when I use Shift+0. The Shift+0 is the shortcut for inputing the ')' char and I expext VS to replace selected text with this char just like every other char input does. But I can't find this disable option in VS or Resharper settings.

Comment: While it's not strictly a duplicate, this question deals with the same issue that has now been built into Visual Studio itself.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964338/how-to-disable-automatic-brace-surrounding-on-selection-in-visual-studio  And the reason this is relevant is that search engines are not perfect, and will turn up this Q & A even if the word "Resharper" is not in the search query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this option under:
`Resharper > Options > Environment > Editor > Editor Behaviour` - Uncheck *`Surround selection on typing a brace or parenthesis.`*