# How to disable automatic brace surrounding on selection in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, formatting

Everything was fine until one update changed a formatting setting and I don't know how to reverse it.

Whenever I select C++ code and try to replace the text with an open brace, it will simply surround the selected text, instead of replacing it with the open brace.

[image: The behavior]

This gets really frustrating after a while, e.g. trying to replace a `<` less symbol with a `>` symbol is now impossible when using selection.
How can I disable this behavior?

---

*I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.4.0*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To disable this mode, head to:

<kbd>Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Options</kbd> -> <kbd>Text Editor</kbd> -> <kbd>C/C++</kbd> -> <kbd>Advanced</kbd>

and set `Auto Surround Mode` to `Never`.

[image: Disable Auto Surround Mode]

Comment: Note: I had this problem a few weeks ago and it took me 5-10 minutes to find the setting. Today it happened again and I couldn't remember where it was, so I decided to document it to end this problem once and for all.

Comment: You should accept your own answer as the solution. I don't know who at Microsoft thought this should become the default behavior for surrounding selected text, it's awful.

Comment: The argument you'll hear from Microsoft is that if they *don't* make it the default, the majority of people will never know it's been added, including those that might actually want it.  I understand that this is a bit of a polarizing issue, but if you read the blog page about this feature, there are several responses from people that think it's the greatest thing to ever happen to VS.  At least the option to turn it off does exist, even it fairly well hidden.